# GAE/P: Migrating to NDB efficiently

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm finally upgrading from `db` to `ndb` (it is a much bigger headache than I anticipated...).

I used a lot of `ReferenceProperty` and I've converted these to `KeyProperty`.  Now, every place where I used a `ReferenceProperty` I need to add an explicit get because it was previously done for me automatically.

My question relates to whether I should restructure my code to make it more efficient.  I have many methods that use a `KeyProperty` and I need to do an explicit `get()`.  I'm wondering if I should change these methods so that I am passing the entity to them instead of using the `KeyProperty` and a `get()`.

Is the automatic memcaching for `ndb` good enough that I don't need to restructure?  Or should I restructure my code to avoid repeated gets of the same entity?

We are not looking at huge inefficiencies here.  But for a single HTTP GET/POST I might be getting the same entity 3-5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the [In-Context Cache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext) will take over and save you the db calls:

> The in-context cache is fast; this cache lives in memory. When an NDB function writes to the Datastore, it also writes to the in-context cache. When an NDB function reads an entity, it checks the in-context cache first. If the entity is found there, no Datastore interaction takes place.

Each request will get a new context.